# Uploading a picture then saving the location in a MySQL database using php.

Tags: php, mysql, upload, image

Here is what I'm trying to do:

I have a normal form with some fields and at the bottom there is a field with a browse button. I can press the browse button and select a file (from my computer) after filling in all the textfields and then click send. Then the picture will be uploaded to a folder at my FTP server and the name of the file or the full location of the file will be saved to a MySQL database together with the information in the other fields.

I know how to save text from textfields but I just wanted to give you guys the full picture of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: The file field doesn't allow you to save the *location* of where the file exists, it actually sends the binary data of the file's contents. You have to save the data on the server, you won't get the full location.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Comment: @zzzBov The location of the file is initially in `$_FILES['field_name']['tmp_name']`. Of course, you can then move it using `move_uploaded_file()` and save that location to the DB

Comment: you did not give us your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done something similar. I created a standard file uploader that uploaded to (in my case) /var/www/uploads/. All I then had to do was find out my filename and the path I stored in the db would be '/var/www/uploads/filename.ext', replacing filename.ext with what was provided by the $_FILES array.